# Characterization of Reflexive Banach Space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Prove that a real Banach Space $X$ is reflexive if and only if each pair of disjoint closed, convex subsets of  $X$, one of which is bounded, can be strictly separated by a hyperplane.

The theorem is stated and proved in the book [Geometric Functional Analysis and its Applications](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781468493719) by Richard Holmes on page-161, which goes like this

> We shall show that the disjoint closed convex sets $H$ and $U(M)$ cannot be strictly separated. Suppose otherwise; then there would exist $\psi\in X^*$ and a positive number $\gamma$ such that $\psi(x)<\gamma<\psi(y)$ for all $x\in U(M)$ and $y\in H$. Let us assume that $\phi$ has been extended to all of $X$ via the Hahn-Banach Theorem, and let us call the extension $\phi$ also. Choose any point $\overline{x}\in X$ such that $\phi(\overline{x})=\|\phi\|$ and any $z\in X$ for which $\phi(z)=0$. Then for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}, \psi(\overline{x}+\lambda z)>\gamma$. Hence, $\psi(z)=0$ and so $\ker(\phi)\subset \ker(\psi)$. This means that the set $\{\phi,\psi\}$ is linearly dependent. We can therefore choose a constant $\alpha$ so that $\psi=\left(\frac{\alpha \gamma}{\|\phi\|}\right) \phi$. Now if $y\in H$ then $\gamma<\psi(y)=\alpha \gamma$, so that $1<\alpha$. On the other hand, if $x\in U(M)$ then $\psi(x)<\gamma$, and so $\phi(x)=\left(\frac{\|\phi\|}{\alpha\gamma}\right)\psi(x)<\frac{\|\phi\|}{\alpha}$; since $\alpha>1$, this contradicts the definition $\|\phi\|=\sup\{\phi(x):x\in U(M)\}$. 
>   I am trying to decipher this proof. It uses the contrapositive logic and is based on the [James Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27s_theorem)  *a Banach space $X$ is reflexive if and only if every continuous linear functional on $X$ attains its supremum on the closed unit ball in $X$.*

And, here is what I could understand in this proof

> Let $X$ be a Banach Space and $M$ be a subspace. Let $\phi\in M^*$ be a continuous linear functional.  Let $H=\{x\in M:\phi(x)=\|\phi\|\}$ be a hyperplane in $M$ and $U(M)=\{x\in M:\|x\|=1\}$ be a unit ball in $M$. Suppose that there exists a continuous linear functional $\psi\in X^*$ and a positive number $\gamma$ such that $\psi(x)<\gamma<\psi(y)$ for all $x\in U(M)$ and $y\in H.$
>
> Choose a point $\overline{x}\in X$ such that $\phi(\overline{x})=\|\phi\|$, i.e. $\overline{x}\in H$ and any $z\in X$ such that $\phi(z)=0$. 
>   Then, for a real number $\lambda$, $\phi(\overline{x}+\lambda z)=\phi(\overline{x})+\lambda \phi(z)$.
>   Since $\overline{x}\in H$ and $\phi(z)=0$,
>    $\phi(\overline{x}+\lambda z)=\|\phi\|+\lambda. 0$.
>    $\implies \phi(\overline{x}+\lambda z)=\|\phi\|$. 
>    $\implies \overline{x}+\lambda z\in H$.
>    $\implies \psi(\overline{x}+\lambda z)>\gamma$.
>   What I couldn't understand is

1. How the idea of extending $\phi$ is applied in all of this?
2. How do you infer $\psi(z)=0$?

Comment: What definition(s) of "reflexive" do you have?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be a good idea to give some context and outline what you have already tried.

Comment: The definition of Reflexive Banach space is based on the The James Theorem: a Banach space $X$ is reflexive if and only if every continuous linear functional on $X$ attains its supremum on the closed unit ball in $X$.

Comment: $\psi(z) = 0$ since we already know that $\psi(\bar{x} + \lambda z) > \gamma$ for any real $\lambda$. If $\lambda > 0$, then $\psi(z) > \lambda^{-1} (\gamma - \psi(\bar{x}))$, and letting $\lambda$ tend to $\infty$ yields $\psi(z) \geq 0$. Similarly, by considering $\lambda < 0$ we have $\psi(z) \leq 0$, and it follows $\psi(z) = 0$. I don't see where the subspace $M$ comes from and what it is used for. It seems that you just need to define $H := \{x \in X: \phi(x) = ||\phi|| \}$, where $\phi$ is a continuous linear functional that fails to attain supremum on the unit ball.

Comment: Thanks a lot, YeZ.

Comment: Note that the extension does not increase the norm.